# Prometheus Monitoring for Remote network

Tags: prometheus

I am very new at Prometheus.
I am currently a working student and my task is to build a monitoring system for servers running on client side (not accessible by us). I have installed node exporter and slave Prometheus serves at the client side (Ubuntu VM, Kubernetes nodes). We have a centralised master Prometheus server and Grafana hosted on AWS, but it cannot reach the client Prometheus server.

Is there any way the slave Prometheus can push the metrics to the master Prometheus server without giving them access to each other? I tried other ways like installing Graphite remote adapter and configuring the slave Prometheus remote write, but there was some issue with the adapter. Will Prometheus Telegraf and influxdb work in this case?

I am sorry if I framed my question wrong.

UPDATE:

This is my MASTER Prometheus server's .yml file: (this one has remote write enabled). This server is the central one, so it is supposed to get all metrics from all remote client Prometheus servers.

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s 
  evaluation_interval: 15s 
  
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'Scoutastic-prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['10.0.4.175:9090']
```

This is a client Prometheus server's (unreachable) .yml file.
This has remote write url of master Prometheus.

```yaml
gloabal:
  scrape_interval:     5m
  evaluation_interval: 5m

remote_write:
 - url: http://10.0.4.175:9090/api/v2/write
   write_relabel_configs:
   - source_labels: [_node_]
     action: keep

   queue_config:
     capacity: 10000
     max_shards: 10
     min_shards: 2
     max_samples_per_send: 5000
     batch_send_deadline: 30m
     min_backoff: 50ms
     max_backoff: 1s

scrape_configs:
   - job_name: 'node'
     scrape_interval: 5s
     static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9100']
```

I don’t have any configuration other than this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus can push ([remote_write](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#remote_write)) and pull ([remote_read](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#remote_read)) metrics from other services and Prometheus instances. This is primarily intended for a long term storage; if you want to alert using that data, it may require tuning as the data comes with a delay.

To make Prometheus push metrics to another Prometheus you need to start the receiving one with this flag:

```
--enable-feature=remote-write-receiver
```

Then configure [remote_write](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#remote_write) on your sender instance:

```yaml
remote_write:
- url: http://your-main-prometheus.com/api/v1/write
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I followed your instructions carefully and did all the installation, I see there is a data flow between the 2 networks. I used Prometheus_remote_write_smaple_total to check and the figures were more than 0. But that's it. I am not able to get any other metrics like CPU, memory usage, etc of the remote network. Am I missing out on something?

Comment: @UzmasamanChanderki there isn't much I can help without any details. Check logs on both instances, maybe there are some errors. Also, check that the metrics you wish to see are present in the secondary Prometheus.

Comment: Thank you. I added few more details in the question. If you can please help it would be great. Sorry for the structure of question. It is not too good. I am new in this forum.

Comment: @UzmasamanChanderki remove `write_relabel_configs` from your secondary Prometheus configuration. Node exporter metrics by default have no `_node_` label, while you made it so that only metrics with `_node_` label make their way to your primary server.

Comment: @UzmasamanChanderki Also, [this doc](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#overview) mentions that the `url` should be `/api/v1/write` (you used v2). At last, I would have rather removed `queue_config` until you got things running.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked I guess. Secondary prometheus is trying to send metrics to the central prometheus but I got error: prometheus_1          | ts=2021-12-03T14:18:31.460Z caller=dedupe.go:112 component=remote level=warn remote_name=2cb2b7 url=http://10.0.4.175:9090/api/v1/write msg="Failed to send batch, retrying" err="Post \"http://10.0.4.175:9090/api/v1/write\": context deadline exceeded"

Comment: I increased the scraping interval as well but getting the same error. Also how do I know that there is indeed a data transfer. I mean where can I access this pushed data in the central prometheus? I didnt get any logs just "server is ready to listen" (on the central prometheus)

Comment: @UzmasamanChanderki you can access the pushed metrics the same way as the collected ones.